# Can I use the same schema markup for my subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, schema.org

I've already used an `Organization` schema markup for my main site.

Can I use the same for my subdomain (which is a review site)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it as long as is the same company and **that info is already present in the subdomain**.

Be aware that [Google's snippet](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) is only a small part of [organization schema](http://schema.org/Organization), so maybe there are extra fields you can use in your subdomain that differs from the original schema.

In addition, don't forget to use [ratings & reviews schema](http://schema.org/Review) in your subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. I think its fine with just mentioning the root domain there. Because you are describing 0r show a company and sub-domain is a part of that...

Answer (score 0):

Google's John Mueller says that schema should generally be unique and implemented on a page which has the schema data as its main focus: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-structured-data-unique-page/239507/

It sounds like your main domain home page is the correct place for your organization schema.   It shouldn't be reused on the sub-domain or even on other pages on the main domain.